# Boundingbox defintion for opencv object tracking

Tags: python, opencv, video-tracking

How is the boundingbox object defined that takes opencv's tracker.init() function?
is it `(xcenter,ycenter,boxwidht,boxheight)`
or `(xmin,ymin,xmax,ymax)`
or `(ymin,xmin,ymax,xmax)`
or something completely different?

I am using python and OpenCV 3.3 and i basically do the following on each object i want to track for each frame of a video:

```
tracker = cv2.trackerKCF_create()
ok = tracker.init(previous_frame,bbox)
bbox = tracker.update(current_frame)
```

Comment: Rect objects in opencv are defined as (x,y,w,h) normally, x and y are from the top left point, and w is width and h the height

Comment: so basically: (xmin,ymin,boxwidth,boxheight) ?

Comment: Normally is like that, but I haven't tested those functions

Comment: i tested it, you are right

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The Answer is: `(xmin,ymin,boxwidth,boxheight)`

Answer (score 6):

The other post states the answer as a fact, so let's look at how to figure it out on your own.

The Python version of OpenCV is a wrapper around the main C++ API, so when in doubt, it's always useful to consult either the [main documentation](https://docs.opencv.org/3.4.0/index.html), or even the [source code](https://github.com/opencv/opencv). There is a [short tutorial](https://docs.opencv.org/3.4.0/da/d49/tutorial_py_bindings_basics.html) providing some basic information about the Python bindings.

First, let's look at [`cv::TrackerKCF`](https://docs.opencv.org/3.4.0/d2/dff/classcv_1_1TrackerKCF.html). The [`init`](https://docs.opencv.org/3.4.0/d0/d0a/classcv_1_1Tracker.html#a4d285747589b1bdd16d2e4f00c3255dc) member takes the bounding box as an instance of [`cv::Rect2d`](https://docs.opencv.org/3.4.0/dc/d84/group__core__basic.html#ga894fe0940d40d4d65f008a2ca4e616bd) (i.e. a variant of [`cv::Rect_`](https://docs.opencv.org/3.4.0/d2/d44/classcv_1_1Rect__.html) which represents the parameters using `double` values):

```
bool cv::Tracker::init(InputArray image, const Rect2d& boundingBox)
```

Now, the question is, how is a `cv::Rect2d` (or in general, the variants of `cv::Rect_`) represented in Python? I haven't found any part of documentation that states this clearly (although I think it's hinted at in the tutorials), but there is some useful information in the bindings tutorial mentioned earlier:

> ... 
>  But there may be some basic OpenCV datatypes like Mat, Vec4i,
>   Size. They need to be extended manually. For example, a Mat type
>   should be extended to Numpy array, Size should be extended to a tuple
>   of two integers etc. 
>  ... 
>  All such manual wrapper functions are placed
>   in `modules/python/src2/cv2.cpp`.

Not much, so let's look at [the code](https://github.com/opencv/opencv/blob/master/modules/python/src2/cv2.cpp) they point us at. Lines [941](https://github.com/opencv/opencv/blob/master/modules/python/src2/cv2.cpp#L941)-[954](https://github.com/opencv/opencv/blob/master/modules/python/src2/cv2.cpp#L954) are what we're after:

```
template<>
bool pyopencv_to(PyObject* obj, Rect2d& r, const char* name)
{
    (void)name;
    if(!obj || obj == Py_None)
        return true;
    return PyArg_ParseTuple(obj, "dddd", &r.x, &r.y, &r.width, &r.height) > 0;
}

template<>
PyObject* pyopencv_from(const Rect2d& r)
{
    return Py_BuildValue("(dddd)", r.x, r.y, r.width, r.height);
}
```

The `PyArg_ParseTuple` in the first function is quite self-explanatory. A 4-tuple of double (floating point) values, in the order x, y, width and height.